# proportional WHERE statement in mysql applying to DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have generic table with `created_at` and `updated_at` dates/fields (mysql)

I need to find all rows where distance between `updated_at` and `DateTime.now` is less than 25% of total `DateTime.now` - `created_at` time

EXAMPLE: I need to get rows that were `created 1 hour ago` and were `updated less than 15 minutes ago` in scope with rows that were `created 4 hours ago` and were updated `less then a hour ago`

In other words (plain math):

`updated_at - created_at < (DateTime.now - created_at)*25/100`

How do I do this?

Comment: If you take what you've done in the math section, and cast the results of the date operations into seconds (mysql specific probably) then what you have there should work shouldn't it?  (watch out for int vs float math)

Comment: all salt is in precise mysql operations where i can spend too much time finding out how to carefully subtract datetimes, pass DateTime.now (or use mysql analog) and, as you correctly mentioned, watching out for int vs float on each operation.. and maybe there is a way not to convert to integers at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. it was easy...

```
SELECT `rows`.* FROM `rows` where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, updated_at, created_at)<TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), created_at)*25/100;
```

due to two nice functions:

- [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php)
- [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)